# Read into variables from a variable

Tags: bash

How can you "read" into variables using IFS and a variable?

I am trying to loop over some data paired by a pipe to be split and worked on.  The error I am getting is `read: 'site|database': not a valid identifier`

```
SITES="abc|abc xyz|asdf"
for site in $SITES;
do
  IFS="|" read domain database <<< echo $site; # es no bueno mi amigo
  echo "Site: $domain \t\t\t Database: $database";
done;
```

Am I just doing this the hard way?  I am not a native Basher. ;)

Comment: All the semicolons in this snippet are useless. The shell grammar is not C :-)

Comment: I come from another language, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your script is that you are not passing the [Here String](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17700.html) to `read` correctly. It should be done like this:

```
IFS=$"|" read domain database <<< "$site" # es no bueno mi amigo
```

Remember to quote the variable as well.

Your script will then work.

Here is the fixed script:

```
SITES="abc|abc xyz|asdf"
for site in $SITES
do
  IFS="|" read domain database <<< "$site" # es no bueno mi amigo
  echo -e "Site: $domain \t\t\t Database: $database"
done
```

It prints:

```
Site: abc                        Database: abc
Site: xyz                        Database: asdf
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  Why is the $ required for this to work as well as the quotes around the here string?

Comment: Take a look at the Bash-Scripting Guide on Here Strings: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17700.html
It is good practice to quote all variables to preserve special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two syntaxes:

```
read a b <<<$variable
```

and

```
read a b < <(command)
```

I'd try this (without messing with `$IFS`):

```
read domain database <<<${site/|/ }
```

Comment: Can you please point me to a doc or something that explains what the "/|/ " part of ${site/|/ } does?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html - bash string manipulations. This specific one is under "Substring Replacement", replaces (only the first) `|` with a space.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only accept one answer, but yours provides me with some great alternatives and I appreciate it.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from voting on answers though (up or down), including the one you accept. (: [you are also free _not_ to vote, of course, you can do whatever you feel like]

Answer (score 0):

I think it's simpler to write:

```
SITES="abc|abc xyz|asdf"
for site in $SITES
do
  domain=${site%|*}      # removes everything from '|' onward
  database=${site#*|}    # removes everything up through '|'
  echo "Site: $domain \t\t\t Database: $database"
done
```

For information on the `${parameter%word}` and `${parameter#word}` notations, see [§3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion in the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts on this.  I will read up on the link you provided.

Answer (score 0):

`IFS` will affect word splitting, but the text is still read on a line by line basis.  However (assuming none of your records contain a newline), you can do:

```
SITES="abc|abc xyz|asdf"
echo "$SITES" | tr \| '\012' | while read domain database; do
  echo "Site: $domain \t\t\t Database: $database";
done
```

To clarify the first sentence, consider the behavior of the following:

```
echo "$SITES" | while read a b c; do echo "a=$a, b=$b"; done
```

and

```
echo "$SITES" | while IFS=\| read a b c; do echo "a=$a, b=$b"; done
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this.